# RecyclerView list row is repeating JsonArray data at the end

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

In the data I'm getting from the server, not a single item is repeating. I debugged my code during this loop, which adds in the model class then sets in the adapter. Again, no single item is repeating.

However, in my list items are repeating after performing the click event on a row button. When I use the methods defined below the text never appears in a row but the number of empty rows is increasing.

```
 /*When I use these 2 methods then it never displays text in the list but increases list*/
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
/*When I use these 2 methods then it never displays text in the list but increases list*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you empty the list before adding data coming from server to your list and setting adapter to your recyclerview